# Why did Lagrange say that Cauchy should learn literature before mathematics?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, quote, lagrange, cauchy

From Bruno Belhoste's [Augustin-Louis Cauchy — A Biography](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2996-4):

> Even if we should doubt the remark Valson attributed to Lagrange, it is likely that he did advise Louis-François about to his son's education in mathematics: Do not allow him even to open a mathematics book nor write a single number before he has completed his studies in literature.

Why did Lagrange say that Cauchy should concentrate his efforts on literature before studying mathematics?

Comment: "I read somewhere" is a bad way to start a question. Maybe you might remember where you read it?

Comment: "Even if we should doubt the remark Valson attributed to Lagrange, it is likely that he did advise Louis-François about to his son's education in mathematics:
Do not allow him even to open a mathematics book nor write a single
number before he has completed his studies in literature" From Cauchy, A biography by Bruno Belhoste